# Getting ID from Database Table in WebAPI 2 (Best Practice)

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-sql

I've a question about best practice to get ID from a Table in the database MS SQL Server.

I'm using WebAPI as a REST Service in C# and the Database SQL Server 2014.

I get the data in JSON format as follows:

```
{
 "Id":1,
 "name":"Deutschland",
 "code":"DE",
 "state":[]
}
```

My Controller is programmed as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetGroup(int id)
{
   Group group = (
             from g in db.QR_Groups
             where g.Id == id
             select new Group
             {
               Id = g.Id,
               name = g.name,
               code = g.code
             }).SingleOrDefault();

   if (group == null)
   {
      throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
   }

   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, group);
}
```

My database table is called "QR_Groups". Is this a good practice how I've programmed?

Answer (score 2):

This may be a question best asked on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but one thing I would advise is that you look into the [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) instead of coding the application and data layers separately.

Using Entity Framework, this method could be reduced in size and made much more readable in the form:

```
var group = context.QR_Groups.Find(id).SingleOrDefault();
```

Hope this at least gives an idea?

Comment: This code I had programmed before. Is this better then the code above in my post? Or is the advantage only that the code is less than the code above?

Comment: Essentially, the two methods are compiled down to be the same, it's more personal preference as to how you like to read the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be get all records of group and then after filter to apply. But here to apply filter and get object

```
var group = context.QR_Groups.where(x=>x.Id==id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Is your code better practice then the other examples? I mean the other codes also filter the Id isn't it?

Comment: when you write this "from g in db.QR_Groups" then all data getting from database in store g then after filtered. But my query is filtered at first time and return result

Comment: Not say thanks if it is help out then right mark answer

Comment: @MukeshKalgude Why use .Where(x => x.Id == id) and not just .Find(id)?